# CMake CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX completely ignored

Tags: windows, powershell, cmake

I'm trying to build protobuf on my windows machine according to [this guide](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/cmake/README.md) (official proto guide). Compiling works fine. But. I would like to install it in my workspace, where other project can have easy access to it. According to the guide I should specify the install prefix like so:

```
 C:\Path\to\protobuf\cmake\build\release>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ^
 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../../../install ^
 ../..
```

This does not have the desired effect as the end result installs in C:\ .
Also if I use an env variable:

```
 $Env:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:/Users/uname/Workspace/protobuf-3.18.0/install"
 cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..\..
```

Or

```
 $Env:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="C:\Users\uname\Workspace\protobuf-3.18.0\install"
 cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..\..
```

I get a slightly different outcome. It tries to install in:

```
C:\Program files (x86)\Protobuf\lib
```

And off course fails due to lack of priveliges. Is it possible to arrange the env in powershell in such a way that cmake actually picks up the install prefix ***that ***I*** want***?

Comment: CMake [has never honored](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-env-variables.7.html) `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as an environment variable.

Comment: Use absolute paths with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` unless you like surprises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as a *cache variable*, not as an *environment variable*, and you should always use *absolute paths*, rather than relative.

```
C:\Path\to\protobuf\cmake\build\release>cmake -G "NMake Makefiles" ^
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ^
  "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/uname/Workspace/protobuf-3.18.0/install" ^
  ../..
```